# Firebase, Flutter - read, retrieve filtered data

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My Firebase Firestore data structure looks like this

```
/users/user1/data/userinfo (String name: Jack, String surname: Johnson)
/users/user2/data/userinfo (String name: Tom, String surname: Ronson)
/users/user3/data/userinfo (String name: Jack, String surname: Dalton)
/users/user4/data/userinfo (String name: Bob, String surname: Smith)
```

In brackets is the content of the respective userinfo documents

And I want to retrieve all the userinfo documents from the /users/ collection where name == Jack, so I should retrieve `/users/user1/data/userinfo(name: Jack, surname: Johnson)` and `/users/user3/data/userinfo(name: Jack, surname: Dalton)`. Could someone help me how to do it in Flutter **without** retrieving the whole /users/ collection and filtering the data on the device, locally.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires only a simple query to your collection.

```
final documents = await usersCollection.where("name", isEqualTo: "Jack").getDocuments();

documents.forEach((doc) => print(doc.data));
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the basic question, I am still learning. I am grateful for your help :)

Comment: No problem mate :)